# R: how to add L1 norm line to plot from glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I'm doing lasso regression, and I want to choose some beta coefficients that best explain my model by using **Leave one out cross validation**. 
Here is my code:

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(19875)
n=100
p=500
real_p=15
x=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
y=as.matrix(apply(x[, 1:real_p], 1, sum) + rnorm(n))
lasso=glmnet(x,y,alpha = 1)
plot(lasso)
#computing loocv 
cvlassofit<-cv.glmnet(x,y, nfolds =n, grouped = FALSE )
plot(cvlassofit)
```

The first plot generates the beta coefficient paths: 
[image]

Then I want to add a vertical line that chooses the best coefficients that have small mean square error. The plot should then look like this: 
[image]

In the code part where I do **CV** I get the best lambda that has the smallest **mse(mean square error)**. 
Here is the plot:

[image]

Now, can I somehow based on the lambda get a value for the L1 norm, so that I could add a vertical line to the first plot? Or instead of **log(lambda)** in the last plot, could I do a **L1 norm**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, can I somehow based on the lambda get a value for the L1 norm, so that I could add a vertical line to the first plot? Or instead of **log(lambda)** in the last plot, could I do a **L1 norm**?

You can do it as follows:

```r
lambda_min <- cvlassofit$lambda.min
estimates <- as.vector(coef(lasso, s = lambda_min, exact = TRUE))
norm. <- sum(abs(estimates))
plot(lasso, xlim = range(0, norm., as.vector(lasso$beta)))
abline(v = norm., col = "red")
```

Here is the result:

[image: plot with line of CV L1 norm]